# Cannot convert Flickr API link to JSON object. Type Mismatch

Tags: java, android, json, flickr

I am tired of this issue, cant figure out why is this happening. I have Four classes. MainActivity, GetRawData, GetFlickrJsonData, Photo. Problem is occuring at GetFlickrJsonData, I have a JSON object that uses the link for Flickr API. But it just fails.

My MainActivity does this function only for now:

```
GetFlickrJsonData data = new GetFlickrJsonData("android, lollipop", true);
data.execute();
```

My GetRawData:

```
enum DownloadStatus {
IDLE, PROCESSING, NOT_INITIALISED, FAILED_OR_EMPTY, OK
};

public class GetRawData {

private String LOG_TAG = GetRawData.class.getSimpleName();
private String mData;
private String mGetRawUrl;
private DownloadStatus mDownloadStatus;

public GetRawData(String mGetRawData) {
    this.mGetRawUrl = mGetRawData;
    this.mDownloadStatus = DownloadStatus.IDLE;
}


public void reset() {
    this.mDownloadStatus = DownloadStatus.IDLE;
    this.mGetRawUrl = null;
    this.mData = null;
}


public String getmGetRawUrl() {
    return mGetRawUrl;
}

public String getmData() {
    return mData;
}

public void setmGetRawUrl(String mGetRawUrl) {
    this.mGetRawUrl = mGetRawUrl;
}

public DownloadStatus getmDownloadStatus() {
    return mDownloadStatus;
}

public void execute() {
    this.mDownloadStatus = DownloadStatus.PROCESSING;
    DownloadRawData downloadrawdata = new DownloadRawData();
    downloadrawdata.execute(mGetRawUrl);
}

public class DownloadRawData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    protected void onPostExecute(String webData) {
        mData = webData;
        //Log.v(LOG_TAG, "data returned is:" + mData);
        if (mData == null) {
            if (mGetRawUrl == null) {
                mDownloadStatus = DownloadStatus.NOT_INITIALISED;
            } else {
                mDownloadStatus = DownloadStatus.FAILED_OR_EMPTY;
            }
        } else {
            mDownloadStatus = DownloadStatus.OK;
        }


    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpURLConnection urlconnection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        if (params == null) {
            return null;
        }

        try {

            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            urlconnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlconnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlconnection.connect();

            InputStream inputstream = urlconnection.getInputStream();
            if (inputstream == null) {
                return null;
            }
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputstream));
            String line;

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line + "\n");
            }
            return buffer.toString();


        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error", e);
            return null;
        } finally {
            if (urlconnection != null) {
                urlconnection.disconnect();
            }
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }


    }
  }
}
```

My Photo class have following Strings, rest in it is only its constructor, getters and toString method:

```
public class Photo {

private String mTitle;
private String mAuthor;
private String mAuthorId;
private String mLink;
private String mImage;
private String mTags;


public Photo(String mTitle, String mAuthor, String mAuthorId, String mLink, String mImage, String mTags) {
    this.mTitle = mTitle;
    this.mAuthor = mAuthor;
    this.mAuthorId = mAuthorId;
    this.mLink = mLink;
    this.mImage = mImage;
    this.mTags = mTags;
}


public String getmTitle() {
    return mTitle;
}

public String getmAuthor() {
    return mAuthor;
}

public String getmAuthorId() {
    return mAuthorId;
}

public String getmLink() {
    return mLink;
}

public String getmImage() {
    return mImage;
}

public String getmTags() {
    return mTags;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Photo{" +
            "mTitle='" + mTitle + '\'' +
            ", mAuthor='" + mAuthor + '\'' +
            ", mAuthorId='" + mAuthorId + '\'' +
            ", mLink='" + mLink + '\'' +
            ", mImage='" + mImage + '\'' +
            ", mTags='" + mTags + '\'' +
            '}';
  }
}
```

Here is my GetFlickrJsonData:

```
public class GetFlickrJsonData extends GetRawData {

private String LOG_TAG = GetFlickrJsonData.class.getSimpleName();
private List<Photo> mPhotos;
private Uri mDestination;

public GetFlickrJsonData(String searchCriteria, boolean matchAll) {
    super(null);
    createAndUpdateUri(searchCriteria, matchAll);
    mPhotos = new ArrayList<>();
}

public void execute() {
    super.setmGetRawUrl(mDestination.toString());
    DownloadJsonData downloadJsonData = new DownloadJsonData();
    Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Build url: " + mDestination.toString());
    downloadJsonData.execute(mDestination.toString());
}


public boolean createAndUpdateUri(String searchCriteria, boolean matchAll) {
    final String FLICKER_API_BASE_URL = "https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne";
    final String TAGS_PARAM = "tags";
    final String TAGMODE_PARAM = "tagmode";
    final String FORMAT_PARAM = "format";
    final String NO_JASON_CALLBACK_PARAM = "nojasoncallback";

    mDestination = Uri.parse(FLICKER_API_BASE_URL).buildUpon()
            .appendQueryParameter(TAGS_PARAM, searchCriteria)
            .appendQueryParameter(TAGMODE_PARAM, matchAll ? "ALL" : "ANY")
            .appendQueryParameter(FORMAT_PARAM, "json")
            .appendQueryParameter(NO_JASON_CALLBACK_PARAM, "1")
            .build();

    return mDestination != null;


}


public void processResult() {
    if (getmDownloadStatus() != DownloadStatus.OK) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error downloading raw file");
        return;
    }

    final String FLICKR_TITLE = "title";
    final String FLICKR_ITEMS = "items";
    final String FLICKR_AUTHOR = "author";
    final String FLICKR_AUTHOR_ID = "author_id";
    final String FLICKR_TAGS = "tags";
    final String FLICKR_URL = "link";
    final String FLICKR_PHOTO_URL = "m";
    final String FLICKR_MEDIA = "media";


    try {
        JSONObject jsonData = new JSONObject(getmData());
        JSONArray itemsArray = jsonData.getJSONArray(FLICKR_ITEMS);
        for (int i = 0; i < itemsArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonPhoto = itemsArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String title = jsonPhoto.getString(FLICKR_TITLE);
            String author = jsonPhoto.getString(FLICKR_AUTHOR);
            String authorId = jsonPhoto.getString(FLICKR_AUTHOR_ID);
            String tags = jsonPhoto.getString(FLICKR_TAGS);
            String link = jsonPhoto.getString(FLICKR_URL);

            JSONObject media = jsonPhoto.getJSONObject(FLICKR_MEDIA);
            String photoUrl = media.getString(FLICKR_PHOTO_URL);

            Photo photoObject = new Photo(title, author, authorId, link, tags, photoUrl);
            this.mPhotos.add(photoObject);
        }

        for (Photo pho : mPhotos) {
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, pho.toString());
        }

    } catch (JSONException jsone) {
        Log.e("LOG", "Error parsing json data");
        jsone.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public class DownloadJsonData extends DownloadRawData {

    protected void onPostExecute(String webData) {
        super.onPostExecute(webData);
        processResult();
    }


    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        return super.doInBackground(params);
    }
}

}
```

Stack Trace:

```
08-14 14:06:02.755: W/System.err(28798): org.json.JSONException: Value jsonFlickrFeed( of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
08-14 14:06:02.770: W/System.err(28798):    at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
08-14 14:06:02.770: W/System.err(28798):    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:159)
08-14 14:06:02.770: W/System.err(28798):    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:172)
08-14 14:06:02.770: W/System.err(28798):    at org.example.flickrbrowser.GetFlickrJsonData.processResult(GetFlickrJsonData.java:73)
08-14 14:06:02.770: W/System.err(28798):    at org.example.flickrbrowser.GetFlickrJsonData$DownloadJsonData.onPostExecute(GetFlickrJsonData.java:105)
08-14 14:06:02.770: W/System.err(28798):    at org.example.flickrbrowser.GetFlickrJsonData$DownloadJsonData.onPostExecute(GetFlickrJsonData.java:101)
08-14 14:06:02.770: W/System.err(28798):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
08-14 14:06:02.770: W/System.err(28798):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
08-14 14:06:02.770: W/System.err(28798):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
08-14 14:06:02.770: W/System.err(28798):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-14 14:06:02.770: W/System.err(28798):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-14 14:06:02.770: W/System.err(28798):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5158)
08-14 14:06:02.770: W/System.err(28798):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-14 14:06:02.770: W/System.err(28798):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-14 14:06:02.770: W/System.err(28798):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:796)
08-14 14:06:02.770: W/System.err(28798):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:612)
08-14 14:06:02.770: W/System.err(28798):    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132)
08-14 14:06:02.770: W/System.err(28798):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can you post the content of JSONObject, you are getting.

Comment: I cant even create JSONObject, how can I tell you about its content?

Comment: You can show us the String content means value of mData that you are trying to convert into JSONObject. I suspect that string is not a valid JSON

Comment: When I type `JSONObject jsonData = new JSONObject(getmData());` it fails to create JSONObject. `getmData()` is URL.

Comment: Here's value of mData: http://pastebin.com/7civb1hd

Thanks for help, it has `jasonFlickrFeed (` that was causing error because I misspelled json to jason in `final String NO_JASON_CALLBACK_PARAM = "nojasoncallback";`. Thanks again for help!